# Why doesn't Project Valhalla introduce mutable structs?

Tags: java, primitive-types, value-type, jep, project-valhalla

Looks to me like primitive classes could behave more efficiently (at reasonable sizes) if they weren't immutable as currently proposed, but worked more like C structs.

Given this primitive class

```
primitive class Point implements Shape {
    public long x;
    public long y;

    public Point(long x, long y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public boolean contains(Point p) {
        return equals(p);
    }
}

interface Shape {
    boolean contains(Point p);
}
```

And an array `Point[] points = new Point[N];`

Why wouldn't we be able to do this?

```
points[0].x = 42;      //lastore
points[1].x++;         //laload, iinc, lastore

Point p = points[2];   //laload, laload
Shape s = p;           //new Point.ref (boxing)
p.x++;                 //iinc
assert !s.contains(p);
```

Instead it sounds like current design intends for the whole Point be read, mutated using `withfield` and written back in its entirety, which seems kind of wasteful - especially for larger types. Or would compilers routinely apply copy elision here?

Note that `Point` **must** be flattened instead of flattenable here, so the user can be certain not to mutate a shared instance.

Could someone further clarify the rationale behind immutability of primitive types?

@see

- [JEP 401: Primitive Classes (Preview)](https://openjdk.org/jeps/401)
- [State of Valhalla - Part 3: The JVM Model](https://github.com/openjdk/valhalla-docs/blob/main/site/design-notes/state-of-valhalla/03-vm-model.md)

Comment: maybe the question in title is better addressed to the mailing list indicated in the JEP you posted: "*Discussion valhalla dash dev at openjdk dot java dot net*"

Comment: @user16320675 Will consider this as a last resort, but I was assuming they have better things to do than explain what's already internal consensus on demand.